# SweetAlert2 not displaying

Tags: php, laravel, google-chrome, sweetalert2, brave

I'm following a tutorial in youtube of php laravel. I am having a difficulty of showing the `sweetalert2` but I followed all the instruction in the video.

> Code in app.js as global the globalJS

```
import swal from 'sweetalert2';
window.swal = swal;

const toast = swal.mixin({
     toast: true,
     position: 'top-end',
    showConfirmButton: false,
    timer: 3000
});  

window.toast = toast;
```

> Code in my User.vue

```
  SaveUser() {
  this.$Progress.start();
  this.form.post("api/user");
  this.loadUsers();
  Toast.fire({
    type: "success",
    title: "Signed in successfully"
  });
  this.$Progress.finish();
}
```

In the documentation [Here](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#download) the code is Toast.fire but in the video that i'm following it is `toast({})`. I tried both code but its not working. Is there a problem in my code?.

> EDIT

I run this code in different computer using Google Chrome `Version 0.69.135 Chromium: 77.0.3865.120 (Official Build) (64-bit)` and `Brave
Version 77.0.3865.120 (Official Build) (64-bit)` and its working fine.

But in my PC 
Brave Version 0.68.142 Chromium: 77.0.3865.90 (Official Build) (64-bit) and `Google Chrome Version 77.0.3865.120 (Official Build) (64-bit)` it's not working.

Comment: Check error messages in Console. and post the error if any. 

Inspect Element -> console

Comment: @IndraKumarS No error shows in console.

Comment: Can you try this.toast.fire in place of Toast.fire

Comment: @IndraKumarS still not showing.